# I roll four fair six-sided dice and total the result. What is the chance the total will be 14?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

this is the given answer.

$$\frac{(6^2+2(5^2+4^2+3^2+2^2+1^2))}{6^4}$$

I just don't get how the numerator is formulated.

Comment: It might be helpful to ignore the given answer and try it before peaking. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you started the process of calculating the number of ways to add to 14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^4$ and find the coefficient of $x^{14}.$ That comes out to $146$. The full expansion also gives the numbers of ways to get any of the possible totals:

$$x^{24} + 4 x^{23} + 10 x^{22} + 20 x^{21} + 35 x^{20} + 56 x^{19} + 80 x^{18} + 104 x^{17} + 125 x^{16}+ \\ 140 x^{15} + 146 x^{14} + 140 x^{13} + 125 x^{12} + 104 x^{11} + 80 x^{10} + 56 x^9 + 35 x^8 + 20 x^7\\ + 10 x^6 + 4 x^5 + x^4$$

adding all of the coefficients forms $1296$ possibilities in which

$$\frac{146}{1296}=\frac{73}{648}$$

where the numerator is the number of ways that the four dice total to $14$

$$\frac{6^2+2(5^2+4^2+3^2+2^2+1^2)}{6^4}=\frac{73}{648}$$